# Google Voice PHP API connect directly

Tags: php, google-voice

Has anyone found a way to use google voice to send a phone call without first calling you. I need a phone to ring, but it is not necessary that any particular message be sent or anything. Here is the API I've been looking at. https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API In the API you specify your google voice number and the recipient's number, and then it calls your phone and connects you to the recipient. I'm looking for a way to just connect to the recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this for a system to alert people when a computer system I created needed attention. Text alerts are good...unless you're asleep and can't hear them. So, what I did was create a google voice number and then delete all of the phones off of it, and record a long voicemail. This way, it calls, and goes straight to a message that tells them the system needs attention and then they can just hang up and respond.

Slight work around, but it seems to work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way Google Voice works... to call out you either a) use the web interface, which calls one of your phones then dials the other person or b) you call you own GV number and use the menu to dial out. The API packages I've looked at all use the GV mobile site to dial or send text messages (method a).

The only method I can think of for your scenario would be to get a free VoIP account with a number somewhere and set up a softphone that auto-answers.

But that begs the question... what is your purpose...? web driven prank calls?